# ariflow2: How to render ds_nodash macro as YYYY/MM

Tags: jinja2, airflow

I am currently migrating a job from Airflow 1.10.14 to 2.1.4

In airflow2, I am using the operator `BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator`,  and one of the requirements is to store data in GCS, following this pattern: `gs://datalate/data_source/YYYY/MM/model.`

```py
    partition_sessions_unlimited = BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator(
        task_id="partition_sessions_unlimited",
        dag=aggregation_dag,
        py_file=os.path.join(
            BEAM_SRC_DIR,
            "streaming_sessions",
            "streaming_session_aggregation_pipeline.py",
        ),
        runner="DataflowRunner",
        dataflow_config=DataflowConfiguration(
            job_name="%s_partition_sessions_unlimited" % ds_env,
            project_id=GCP_PROJECT_ID,
            location="us-central1",
        ),
        pipeline_options={
            "temp_location": "gs://dataflow-temp/{}/{}/amazon_sessions/amz_unlimited".format(
                sch_date, ds_env
            ),
            "staging_location": "gs://dataflow-staging/{}/{}/amazon_sessions/amz_unlimited".format(
                sch_date, ds_env
            ),
            "disk_size_gb": "100",
            "num_workers": "10",
            "num_max_workers": "25",
            "worker_machine_type": "n1-highcpu-64",
            "setup_file": os.path.join(
                BEAM_SRC_DIR, "streaming_sessions", "setup.py"
            ),
            "input": "gs://{}/amazon_sessions/{{ ds_nodash[:4] }}/{{ ds_nodash[4:6] }}/amz_unlimited/input/listens_*".format(
                w_datalake,
            ),
            "output": "gs://{}/amazon_sessions/{{ ds_nodash[:4] }}/{{ ds_nodash[4:6] }}/amz_unlimited/output/sessions_".format(
                w_datalake
            ),
        },
    )
```

however, I get

```py
'output': 'gs://datalake/amazon_sessions/{ ds_nodash[:4] }/{ ds_nodash[4:6] }/amz_prime/output/sessions_',
```

instead of

```py
'output': 'gs://datalake/amazon_sessions/2022/02/amz_prime/output/sessions_',
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are using a `format` string for jinja templated field.

`format()` will replace `{var}` to value from params that are passed, if it exists.

```py
"gs://{}/.../{{ ds_nodash[:4] }}...".format(w_datalake)
```

First `{}` is replaced with "datalake" and 2nd part doesn't have any equivalent param that is passed, so resulted in the literal "ds_nodash[:4]".

```
"gs://datalake/.../{ds_nodash[:4]}..."
```

In order to use jinja template within the formatted string, you can escape the `{` and `}` for part you are intended to get value from jinja. To escape `{` you add another `{`, and for `}` you add another `}`. Original one has 2 `{{` so add 2 `{` on each side like this;

```py
"gs://{}/.../{{{{ ds_nodash[:4] }}}}...".format(w_datalake)
```

With this, `format` will be applied first (replacing the value and take out the escape symbol) and turned this string to

```
gs://datalake/.../{{ ds_nodash[:4] }}...
```

then this string is passed to `BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator` where this part is converted with jinja fields.

Secondly, instead of using `ds_nodash` twice with slicing, you can use `execution_date` to format as you like

```py
{{ execution_date.strftime('%Y/%m') }}
```